# How does refeeding syndrome cause pitting edema?

Tags: nutrition, edema

In the answer to "[How do you feed a starving person in a way that won't kill them?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/19204/13163)", it is mentioned that refeeding syndrome can cause peripheral edema. How does this occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During refeeding syndrome (RFS), intake of carbohydrates causes a **massive surge in insulin levels**, leading to electrolyte abnormalities. Increased insulin also caused sodium and water retention independent to changes of renal GFR and RPF [1]. Water retention increases capillary hydrostatic pressure, leading to peripheral edema.

Another possible contributor to peripheral edema during RFS is hypoalbuminemia, which decreases capillary oncotic pressure [2].

Sources:

1. "[The Effect of Insulin on Renal Sodium Metabolism](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%252FBF00252649.pdf)". R.A. DeFronzo
2. "[Refeeding syndrome](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/19931071/)". J. Fuentebella, J.A. Kerner